# TikZ: math mode in axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a fundamental domain of a group with TikZ. The search resulted in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323669/drawing-of-a-set-with-tikz). This is nearly the same as I want so I can adapt the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm, y=3cm]
\begin{scope}[y=1cm]
\clip (-.5,0) coordinate (a) |- (.5,4) coordinate (b) -- (b|- a) arc         (0:180:1/12) arc (0:180:1/6) arc (0:180:1/6) arc (0:180:1/12);
\fill [pattern=north west lines] (-.5,0) rectangle (.5,4);
\end{scope}
\draw [densely dashed, fill=white!1] (a) arc (180:0:1/12) arc (180:0:1/6)  arc (180:0:1/6) arc (180:0:1/12);
\draw (-0.75,0) -- (0.75,0);
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {-1/2,-1/3,0,1/3,1/2}
{\draw (\i,0) coordinate (x\j) edge ++(0,2pt) -- ++(0,-2pt) node [below=5pt,    anchor=mid, font=\scriptsize] {\i};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need help please with the two problems:
The numbers are overlapping and the dashed lines $z=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ are missing. I could draw a line with

```
\draw (-.5,0) -- (-.5,x)
```

but I don't know what x is.

I want to get this, but the two lines are too long:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: @heather, thank you so much, that works! Do you also know how I can add the two lines Re(z)=1/2 and Re(z)=-1/2?

Comment: @mathmarseille, I'll work on it. I'm sorry, this is just me (and you definitely don't *have* to do this) but if you wouldn't mind posting an image of what you want to get, that would be really helpful.

Comment: I added it! Hope the picture helps.

Comment: Glad to help!  Let me know if there's anything else I can add.

Comment: Yes there is something else but I have opened another question since I dont wan't that you think that you have to do all the work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your two problems are

1. That the labels for the axis are on top of each other.
2. That the lines you want to add outlining the sides are too long.

The solution for each particular problem is

1. Scaling it, using the line of code `\begin{tikzpicture}‌​[x=3cm, y=3cm, scale=3]`. The number you scale it by can be less or more, though at some point you'll run into the limits of the page space.
2. Adding the lines of code `\draw[densely dashed] (-1/2,0) -- (-1/2,1.33);`
   and `\draw[densely dashed] (1/2,0) -- (1/2,1.33);` draws the lines fairly accurately.

This gives the overall code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm, y=3cm,scale=3]
    \begin{scope}[y=1cm]
        \clip (-.5,0) coordinate (a) |- (.5,4) coordinate (b) -- (b|- a) 
         arc (0:180:1/12) arc (0:180:1/6) arc (0:180:1/6) arc 
         (0:180:1/12);
        \fill [pattern=north west lines] (-.5,0) rectangle (.5,4);
    \end{scope}
    \draw [densely dashed, fill=white!1] (a) arc (180:0:1/12) arc 
    (180:0:1/6)  arc (180:0:1/6) arc (180:0:1/12);
    \draw (-0.75,0) -- (0.75,0);
    \foreach \i [count=\j] in {-1/2,-1/3,0,1/3,1/2}
        {\draw (\i,0) coordinate (x\j) edge ++(0,2pt) -- ++(0,-2pt) node 
        [below=5pt, anchor=mid, font=\scriptsize] {\i};}
    \draw[densely dashed] (-1/2,0) -- (-1/2,1.33);
    \draw[densely dashed] (1/2,0) -- (1/2,1.33);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the image

[image]

Hope this helps!